# Could not pan Google VrPanoramaView along top/down direction

Tags: android, google-vr

Having used Google VrPanoramaView to load spherical image, I find out that the image cannot be panned along top/down direction. Has Google locked it? or do I need to provide a custom renderer in order to be able to pan along those directions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, I gave up Google lib & came across with another solution.

Comment: vrPanoramaView.setPureTouchTracking(true); you could have used this for pan. This Might Help Someone.